# query that return only number of rows base on amount

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a following table for payable

[image]

**Scenario:**

`We are going to pay 6000 to our vendor, this payment apply on 2nd row and remaining 2500 apply on 3rd row. after apply the 2500 on 3rd row , there will be a remaining balance of 1000.`

`Now I want to write a query that return number of rows base on payment enter. The conditions of query are as follow:`

1. Check the balance greater than 0
2. Return only that rows in which the payment apply. `i.e. In above scenario, payment was 6000, and then query check that in which 6000 apply, base upon that decision it should return rows. In 6000 case he should return 2nd and 3rd row, if payment = 8000 then query will return 3 row because 7000 satisfy/ clear 2nd & 3rd payable and remaining 1000 will reduce the balance of 4th entry.`

I want a query that return only number of rows in which payment apply ?

Update me !

Comment: Please show the expected results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff in case of payment of 6000, query should `return only 2nd and 3rd row(Result)`

Comment: @GordonLinoff `select number of rows where 6000 can apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken into account the request to order by `duedate`, and to know how much is 'left' you get something like the following. This query will get you the amount left from the payment in `left` and the balance after substracting (what's left of) the payment in `new_balance`.

```
SELECT p.*,
    IF(balance < @left, 0, balance - @left) AS 'new_balance',
    @left := IF(balance > @left, 0, @left - balance) AS 'left'
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM payable
      WHERE balance > 0
      ORDER BY duedate, payableid
    ) AS p
  JOIN (SELECT @left := 6000) AS r ON @left > 0
```

The above query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae146/6)

Some notes:

- As `duedate` is not unique I've added `payableid` (which I assume *is* unique) as well.
  For consistency's sake the `ORDER BY` in the subquery for `p` **must** be unique.
- The results returned by the subquery **must** contain only records to which the amount may be credited.
  (so, if you'd had an `account_id` column or some such, you'd include that in the `WHERE` in the subquery).
- The results returned by the subquery **should** be as small as possible for optimaztion's sake
  (hence we place `WHERE balance > 0` in the subquery and *not* in the outer query).
- If you're wondering "why the subquery?": because the `ORDER BY` is executed *after* selection.
  As such, where we not to use a subquery, `@left` would be incorrectly applied and `ORDER BY` would be rendered useless.

Comment: As a note.  This is not going to work consistently unless you have an `order by` in the query.

Comment: @gordon-linoff true indeed; updated post to make that clear for future visitors

Comment: @vollie I shall appreciate, if you write this query in another way that run on all database and I no need column `left` !  because I use this query in hibernate using HQL `ORDER BY DUEDATE`

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by 'all databases', as it *is* valid SQL it should run on all *databases* as it was/is. As far as HQL is concerned, I personally don't have any experience with said QL, but it would seem execution of the above should be possible. Anyway, i've added the `ORDER BY`, improved the `left` and added `new_balance`.